# Javascript: Map function weird behaviour

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code to identify if a character is duplicated, if it is then I replace with a specific char, else another char.

This code works

```
function dup(str) {
  return str
    .toLowerCase()
    .split("")
    .map((index, nonsense, s) => {
      console.log(s);
      return s.indexOf(index) == s.lastIndexOf(index) ? "(" : ")";
    })
    .join("");
}
```

But I do not understand why, the variable 'nonsense' makes it work. If you remove that unused var I get errors.

How can an unused var affect how map works?

Comment: Problem is about argument position, if you remove nonsense, parameter named `s` will shift to 2nd parameter and will not receive expected value

Comment: I'd recommend a peek at [MDN: Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])`, which shows what the parameters are.

Comment: If you dont want to use it, you can underscore it, but giving the property meaning is still useful.  Though, `index` isnt the index.  It is the current character, and nonsense is the index, and s is the base string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the order of the arguments and the value at specific locations

```
function dup(str) {
  return str
    .toLowerCase()
    .split("")
    .map((char, index, self) => { // the order is char, index and the current array in the 3rd argument
      console.log(self);
      return self.indexOf(char) == s.lastIndexOf(char) ? "(" : ")";
    })
    .join("");
}
```

If you wish to remove the issue with unused variable (for example, say with eslint) use the `_` or prefix with `_`

```
function dup(str) {
  return str
    .toLowerCase()
    .split("")
    .map((char, _, self) => { // the order is char, index and the current array in the 3rd argument
      console.log(self);
      return self.indexOf(char) == self.lastIndexOf(char) ? "(" : ")";
    })
    .join("");
}
```

**EDIT**

Though unrelated,a more optimal way to do it would be to use `Set` to deduplicate.

```
function dup(str) {
  return Array.from(new Set(str
    .toLowerCase()
    .split(""))
    .join("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has less to do with `.map()` and more to do with receiving arguments.

The function passed to `.map` is automatically passed 3 arguments (which you are calling `index`, `nonsense`, and `s` here). In JavaScript, you are not required to specifically capture any of them with argument names, but if you want to use the second or third one, you will need to provide some argument name(s) for the ones you are going to skip over to indicate that you are interested in the third argument.

Having said that, the arguments passed to [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (in order) are: ***element***, ***index***, ***array*** and your names suggest that you believe it's: ***index***, ***element***, ***array***. So a better naming convention would be as shown below:

```js
function dup(str) {
  return str
    .toLowerCase()
    .split("")
    .map((char, index, ary) => {
      console.log(ary);
      return ary.indexOf(index) == ary.lastIndexOf(index) ? "(" : ")";
    })
    .join("");
}

dup("The quick quick brown fox.");
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code index represent the current char, nonsense represents the indexOf that char at s array. if you remove nonsense index will be represent the char and s will be represent the indexOf that char. that cause the error because you are trying to do s.indexOf(index) while s is of type number

try to do it like this

```
 function dup(str) {
  return str
    .toLowerCase()
    .split('')
    .map(s => {
      console.log(s)
      return str.indexOf(s) == str.lastIndexOf(s) ? '(' : ')'
    })
    .join('')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

As you can see, the `map` function takes up to three params, where the second and third are optional. Your variables `index`, `nonsense` and `s` are filling in for the current value, the *actual* index and the array. Remove `nonsense` and your `s` variable becomes the current index of `map`, instead of your array.

That is the expected behavior.